# derivative of distance with respect to vector?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vectors

$$
||X - Y||_2 = \left[(X - Y)^T(X - Y)\right]^{\frac{1}{2}}
$$

Accepting that the $\cdot^{\frac{1}{2}}$ operator isn't kosher in vector notation, how do I

- represent that function in vector notation?
- take the derivative with respect to one of the vectors?

I do have a use case--I'm trying to optimize a function of distances with respect to *part* of one of the vectors.

Answer (score 1):

I think a nice approach is to use the chain rule.

Let $y \in \mathbb R^n$ and let
$$
f(x) = \| x - y \|_2 = \left( \| x - y \|_2^2 \right)^{\frac12}.
$$
Notice that $f(x) = g(h(x))$ where $h(x) = \| x - y \|_2^2$ and $g(u) = u^{1/2}$. The derivatives of $g$ and $h$ are
$$
g’(u) = \frac12 u^{-1/2} \quad \text{and} \quad h’(x) = 2(x - y)^T
$$
(assuming $u \neq 0$).

By the chain rule, if $x \neq y$ then $f$ is differentiable at $x$ and
$$
f’(x) = g’(h(x)) h’(x) = \frac{(x - y)^T}{\| x - y \|_2}.
$$

Comment: I'm not sure what I was expecting.  My use case is a sum of two Euclidean distances, $||A - C||_2 + ||C - B||_2$, and I'm trying to minimize that quantity.  Therefore I have to take derivative of both wrt C, set equal to 0, and solve for $C$.   I've done this math but got stuck on the solving, and was hoping I was doing something wrong and there was an easier way.

Comment: By the way, what if you instead just minimize $\| A - C\|_2^2 + \| B - C \|_2^2$? Then there is a simple analytic solution (the mean of $A$ and $B$).

Comment: Well, $A$ and $B$ are on constrained geometries.  Within their constraint, they are hypercubes, and so Euclidean distance works.   And the constrained geometries are adjacent.  So I create an interim point $C$ that lies on the intersection of the geometries of $A$ and $B$, and calculate Euclidean distance to that from both points.  So $C$ has two constraints (or rather, I know 2 parts of $C$.)

Comment: I'm not sure minimizing $(a - c)^2 + (c - b)^2$ is the same as minimizing $\sqrt{(a - c)^2} + \sqrt{(c - b)^2}$.  I guess I should try squaring the whole thing--it might result in a function more easily solved for $c$.

Comment: Minimizing $(a - c)^2 + (b - c)^2$ is not actually equivalent to your original problem, but depending on your application it might be equally useful, and the math is nicer.